# public variables in php

Tags: php, public-method

I have this function:

```
function map(){          
        $address = mashhad; // Google HQ
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
        $ogt=owghat($month , $day , $longitude , $latitude  , 0 , 1 , 0);
}
```

and i need to use form $ogt in another function,is it possible that declared  ogt as a public variable and if it possible how can i do that?

Comment: Not from a function, though if you were using OOP you could do so; but your function doesn't return anything, so why not return $ogt and then you can use it elsewhere

Comment: http://php.net/return

Comment: owghat function return an array and i need to each one of ogt variables so i cant returnt it.of cource i think!

Comment: Your `owghat()` function might return an array, but your `map()` function returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it as a global in the function:

```
function map() {
    //one method of defining globals in a function
    $GLOBALS['ogt'] = owghat($moth, $day, $longitude, $latitude, 0, 1, 0);
    // OR
    //the other way of defining a global in a function
    global $ogt;
    $ogt = owghat($month, $day, $longitude, $latitude, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

**BUT** this isn't the way you should go about this. If we want a variable from a function we just return it from the function:

```
function map() {
    $ogt = owghat($month, $day, $longitude, $latitude, 0, 1, 0);
    return $ogt;
}

$ogt = map(); //defined in global scope.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you declare `$ogt` outside of that function, it will be global to the work you are doing.  You could also call a function from `map()` with `$ogt` as part of the call.  It really depends on what you are doing.  You can also just declare the variable as public as you could in C#.  I would recommend this from the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: it will only be global if you declare it as global within the function definition

Comment: That's why I linked both scope and visibility topics :)  Best to fully understand all options, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare $ogt variable as global variable

Source:

1: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

2: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php